# How do I make my code loop and add the previous result with the new result

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my question is this:
Write   a   program that    asks    the user    to  enter   two numbers.    The numbers
should  be  added   and the sum displayed.  The program will    then    ask the
user    whether he  or  she wants   to  continue    inputting.      If  he  or  she
answers ‘y’ or      ‘yes’,  the program will    ask the user    to  re-enter    two
numbers and calculate the   sum again   (the    sum will    get accumulated).
Otherwise,  the program will    terminate.

Right now the code I have is this:

```
number1 = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
number2 = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))
result = number1 + number2
print("\nThe sum is:", result)

while True:
   a = input("Do you want to continue (Yes or No): ").lower()
   if a == "yes":
       print(
  
   elif a == "no":
       print(
       break
```

But I don't know how to ask the user again to input two new numbers and then add those to the previous result.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you want to continue inputting, the `input` statements should go inside the `while` loop. Moreover, `result` variable should be initialized  in order to be updated. you can add `continue` inside the `if` condition to `restart` the while loop if the answer is `yes`. Furthermore, your program will run even if you don't write `yes`or `no`. To resolve that we can add an `else` statement. Here is the updated code:

```
result=0 #initializing the 'result' variable
while True:
   number1 = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
   number2 = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))
   result += number1 + number2 #updating the result
   print("\nThe sum is:", result )
   a = input("Do you want to continue (Yes or No): ").lower()
   if a == "yes":
      continue #continuing the loop if the answer is yes
   elif a == "no":
       print("bye")
       break
   else:
      print("wrong input !! please try again")
      a = input("Do you want to continue (Yes or No): ").lower()
```

**Test**:

```
Please enter the first number: 2
Please enter the second number: 2

The sum is: 4
Do you want to continue (Yes or No): ll
wrong input !! please try again
Do you want to continue (Yes or No): yes
Please enter the first number: 2
Please enter the second number: 2

The sum is: 8
Do you want to continue (Yes or No): no
bye
```

Comment: Added an answer hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it. Just move the input inside of the loop and store the result outside of it:

```
result = 0

while True:
    number1 = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
    number2 = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))

    result = result + number1 + number2

    print("\nThe sum is:", result)

    a = input("Do you want to continue (Yes or No): ").lower()
    if a != "yes":
       break
```